# oracle sql getting duplicate invoice number according to status

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have below sql query with different invoices having different status.

```
WITH D AS (SELECT  'ABC' INV#,'PROCESSED' STATUS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT  'ABC' INV#,'ERROR' STATUS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT  'XYZ' INV#,'PROCESSED' STATUS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT  'AJSKS' INV#,'ERROR' STATUS FROM DUAL union all
        SELECT  'SPG' INV#,'PROCESSED' STATUS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT  'SPG' INV#,'ERROR' STATUS FROM DUAL
        )
        SELECT * FROM D
```

In case of duplicate Invoice# want to get invoice with status `PROCESSED` otherwise whatever the status is can return.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what your expected output is and whether you expect only duplicated invoices to be returned or whether you want one from each invoice number regardless of whether there are duplicates or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
   select * , row_number() over (partition by INV#, order by case STATUS when 'PROCESSED' then 1 else 0 end desc) rn 
   from D
) t where rn = 1
```

Comment: This won't find duplicates.

Comment: @MT0 why not ? it will work regardless of how many record per invoice there are

Comment: Exactly my point, the OP's title is about getting duplicate invoice numbers and this will also return the non-duplicated ones. I've asked the OP to clarify what they are asking as it seems like we've both interpreted it differently.

Comment: @MT0 depends on what PO expects as their ouput

Answer (score 0):

To find the duplicated rows and return those that are processed in preference to non-processed rows, you can use:

```
SELECT inv#, status
FROM   (
  SELECT d.*,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY inv#) AS cnt,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY inv#
           ORDER BY CASE status WHEN 'PROCESSED' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
         ) AS rn
  FROM   d
)
WHERE  cnt > 1
AND    rn  = 1;
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> | INV# | STATUS |
> | --- | --- |
> | ABC | PROCESSED |
> | SPG | PROCESSED |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=09e3fb0ab731556403130d163c15b2c0)*